# Using Advanced Installer in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, advanced-installer

Ok I have a new problem.  I'm trying to use advanced installer through the Windows Batch command

```
 "C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /edit "C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\Platforms\Win32\Install\myProject.aip" /SetVersion %previousVersion%
 "C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /edit "C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\Platforms\Win32\Install\myProject.aip" /SetProductCode -langid 1033
 "C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /rebuild "C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\Platforms\Win32\Install\myProject.aip"
```

The project hangs when it calls the rebuild command and never completes.

I thought that maybe it might have been a path issue with one of my files in the project so I looked over all of my paths and made they were correct.  I also went into the installer and set all paths to be absolute.

Unfortunately Advance Installer does not show errors on the command prompt, and logs do not work unless the process is finished.

When I run advance installer on our build machine it builds the project with no problems.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Here is my Output log and AI location.  I moved the AIP file to the root directory.

```
Started by user Admin
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
Building remotely on Build 3 in workspace c:\jenkins\workspace\myProject
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
FILE_INSTALLER="C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe"
DIR_INSTALL="C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject"
FILE_INSTALL="myProject.aip"

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[testdev] $ cmd /c call C:\DOCUME~1\SOFTWA~1.NAF\LOCALS~1\Temp\hudson47906.bat

c:\jenkins\workspace\testdev>cd "C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject" 

C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject>dir
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 341D-83B7

Directory of C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject

05/21/2012  09:52 AM    <DIR>          .
05/21/2012  09:52 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/14/2012  01:03 PM    <DIR>          .hg
05/14/2012  09:20 AM               146 .hgignore
05/14/2012  09:20 AM             6,158 .hgtags
05/14/2012  09:20 AM               278 delete compiled files.bat
05/14/2012  09:20 AM               293 file changes.bat
05/15/2012  03:13 PM    <DIR>          myProjectDocs
05/14/2012  09:20 AM    <DIR>          Platforms
05/14/2012  09:20 AM    <DIR>          Universal
05/21/2012  09:52 AM           494,538 myProject.aip
           5 File(s)        501,413 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  26,546,180,096 bytes free

 C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject>"C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /edit "myProject.aip" /SetVersion 2.6.4.17 

 C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject>"C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /edit "myProject.aip" /SetProductCode -langid 1033 

 C:\jenkins\workspace\myProject\myProject>"C:\Program Files\Caphyon\Advanced Installer 8.0.1\bin\x86\advinst.exe" /rebuild "myProject.aip" 
 Build was aborted
 Aborted by Admin
 [PostBuildScript] - Execution post build scripts.
 [PostBuildScript] Build is not success : do not execute script
 Build step '[PostBuildScript] - Execute a set of scripts' marked build as failure
 Finished: ABORTED
```

AI location on the build machine.
[image: AI]

And I do have the Advanced Installer Path listed in the server environmental variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not see output in the command prompt because you are calling "advinst.exe". The [CLI interface of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/command-line.html) was designed to be called through "AdvancedInstaller.com".

Also, I suppose free space is not a problem on the machine?

**UPDATE**: Now there is an [official Jenkins plugin for Advanced Installer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Advanced+Installer+Msi+Builder+Plugin).

Comment: Have you tried "AdvancedInstaller.com" instead of "advinst.exe" and it still presents the same behavior?

Comment: When I tried to use AdvancedInstaller.com I get the error that it's not a Win32 application.

Comment: That is strange, seems like the resources of Advanced Installer got corrupted somehow. Have you tried to run a repair for Advanced Installer and call again "AdvancedInstaller.com"?

Comment: Re-installing helped.  There was a file being pulled from a location that Jenkins did not have access to.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check the machine and make sure no messages are popping up. 
2) Check the version of AI and the version of AI used to create the install file. 
3) Check the version specified and make sure it conforms to the x.x.x.x format.

Comment: 1.) No messages are popping up.  I'm also noticing that AI is not creating a cache folder or .msi file on the machine.  2.) It was created with 8.0.1  3.) %previousversion% is a variable that has x.x.x.x set by default.  I have tested that both edit functions work properly.

Comment: hmm try opening the aip file on the build machine in the jenkins folder and running it manually. (do not pull or do anything jenkins wouldn't do).  This might show the problem.

Comment: I've ran my modified .aip file and it created the installation file with no problems.  The reason I had to modify the .aip file was due to the fact that when jenkins pulls from our repo AI changes the file paths to look for all files in the project directory.

Comment: Next step would be to try to run these commands from command prompt starting in the jenkins job directory (one step at a time) see what step it is stopping or prompting on.  Also, if there is a flag for AI to suppress messages it might be worth passing in

Comment: It builds the exe every time when I run the commands from the command line. I have even ran the command from different areas in the project.

Comment: Jenkins may not be aware of your tool locations.  Can you post the output? (dont post it if it has sensitive info in it though).  Maybe your path from the root to files is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check: run Jenkins in the foreground with (e.g. `java -jar hudson.war`) and not as a service.

Comment: I've tried running it as a service and in the foreground and end up with the same result.